# How to override object's display name in DevTools console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, constructor, google-chrome-devtools, radix

I am using Dean Edwards' Base.js library to provide OOP in javascript. The objects it creates look like "klass.proto.constructor" in Chrome's console. Is it possible to override its display name to show human-readable labels like "MyClass" etc.

I think it could be achieved by playing with toString property, but i have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

In the Chrome console, the object's `toString` isn't called. Instead there is an interactive representation of the object's structure.

See my answer to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31351527/2482570

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you would set

```
Your_object.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "MyClass"; /* or whatever */
}
```

If you need to do this on a regular basis for all the objects returned from Base.js, you have to patch the library :(