# Is it possible to override JavaScript's toString() function to provide meaningful output for debugging?

Tags: javascript, debugging, tostring

When I `console.log()` an object in my JavaScript program, I just see the output `[object Object]`, which is not very helpful in figuring out what object (or even what type of object) it is.

In C# I'm used to overriding `ToString()` to be able to customize the debugger representation of an object. Is there anything similar I can do in JavaScript?

Comment: I find that output is the most reliable way of telling you what a variable holds (or at least better than `typeof`).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can override `toString` in Javascript as well. See example:

```js
function Foo() {}

// toString override added to prototype of Foo class
Foo.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "[object Foo]";
}

var f = new Foo();
console.log("" + f); // console displays [object Foo]
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript) discussion on how to determine object type name in JavaScript.

Comment: In case someone else like me ends up here, you can use Sybmol.toStringTag in ES6 to customize the Object.prototype.toString.call 
 behavior. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag

Answer (score 47):

First override `toString` for your object or the prototype:

```
var Foo = function(){};
Foo.prototype.toString = function(){return 'Pity the Foo';};

var foo = new Foo();
```

Then convert to string to see the string representation of the object:

```
//using JS implicit type conversion
console.log('' + foo);
```

If you don't like the extra typing, you can create a function that logs string representations of its arguments to the console:

```
var puts = function(){
    var strings = Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function(obj){
        return '' + obj;
    });
    console.log.apply(console, strings);
};
```

Usage:

```
puts(foo)  //logs 'Pity the Foo'

puts(foo, [1,2,3], {a: 2}) //logs 'Pity the Foo 1,2,3 [object Object]'
```

### Update

E2015 provides much nicer syntax for this stuff, but you'll have to use a transpiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io):

```
// override `toString`
class Foo {
  toString(){
    return 'Pity the Foo';
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();

// utility function for printing objects using their `toString` methods
const puts = (...any) => console.log(...any.map(String));

puts(foo); // logs 'Pity the Foo'
```

Comment: console.log('' + foo); this was the problem I did not see any toString implementation until I reached to your answer.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Node it might be worth considering `util.inspect`.

```
var util = require('util')

const Point = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  [util.inspect.custom]: function(depth) { return `{ #Point ${this.x},${this.y} }` }

}

console.log( Point );
```

This will yield:

```
{ #Point 1,2 }
```

While the version without inspect prints:

```
{ x: 1, y: 2 }
```

---

More information (+ *an example for using in `class`es*):

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_custom

Answer (score 17):

Add the ['Symbol.toStringTag'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) property to the custom object or class.

The string value which is assigned to it will be its default string description because it is accessed internally by the `Object.prototype.toString()` method.

For example:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
  get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
    return 'Person';
  }
}

let p = new Person('Dan');
Object.prototype.toString.call(p); // [object Person]
```

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
  get[Symbol.toStringTag]() {
    return 'Person';
  }
}

let p = new Person('Dan');
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(p));
```

Some Javascript types such as Maps and Promises have a built-in `toStringTag` symbol defined

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Map());       // "[object Map]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(Promise.resolve()); // "[object Promise]"
```

Because `Symbol.toStringTag` is a [well-known symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Well-known_symbols), we can reference it and verify that the above types do have the Symbol.toStringTag property -

```
new Map()[Symbol.toStringTag] // 'Map'
Promise.resolve()[Symbol.toStringTag] // 'Promise'
```

Comment: Is this together with overriding `toString()` directly the only way to achieve `function MyObj() {} Object.prototype.toString.call(new MyObj()) // "[object MyObj]"`?

Comment: @tonix - I think so... If there's another way, please let me know ;)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for any code written in the last three or four years. As an aside, it's useful in mocking classes in unit tests so you can check the type of object you're instantiating.

Answer (score 14):

An easy way to get debuggable output in browser JS is to just serialize the object to JSON. So you could make a call like

```
console.log ("Blah: " + JSON.stringify(object));
```

So for an example, `alert("Blah! " + JSON.stringify({key: "value"}));` produces an alert with the text `Blah! {"key":"value"}`

Comment: That is pretty handy. The output can be a bit huge I imagine, but works in a pinch!

Comment: @dev Handy, but doesn't override toString().

Comment: Just be careful with circular references and functions.

Answer (score 11):

With [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
class Foo {
  toString() {
     return 'I am foo';
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(`${foo}`); // 'I am foo'
```

Answer (score 7):

If the object is defined by yourself you can always add a toString override.

```js
//Defined car Object
var car = {
  type: "Fiat",
  model: 500,
  color: "white",
  //.toString() Override
  toString: function() {
    return this.type;
  }
};

//Various ways to test .toString() Override
console.log(car.toString());
console.log(car);
alert(car.toString());
alert(car);

//Defined carPlus Object
var carPlus = {
  type: "Fiat",
  model: 500,
  color: "white",
  //.toString() Override
  toString: function() {
    return 'type: ' + this.type + ', model: ' + this.model + ', color:  ' + this.color;
  }
};

//Various ways to test .toString() Override
console.log(carPlus.toString());
console.log(carPlus);
alert(carPlus.toString());
alert(carPlus);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just override the `toString()` method.

Simple example:

```
var x = {foo: 1, bar: true, baz: 'quux'};
x.toString(); // returns "[object Object]"
x.toString = function () {
    var s = [];
    for (var k in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(k)) s.push(k + ':' + this[k]);
    }
    return '{' + s.join() + '}';
};
x.toString(); // returns something more useful
```

It does even better when you define a new type:

```
function X()
{
    this.foo = 1;
    this.bar = true;
    this.baz = 'quux';
}

X.prototype.toString = /* same function as before */

new X().toString(); // returns "{foo:1,bar:true,baz:quux}"
```

Comment: This code does not solve the OP's console.log issue, at least not in node.js `v0.10.*` or Chrome `Version 32.0.1700.102`.

While calling toString directly (lame) or using type coercion (lamer) will work with this, console[/info|log/] uses to old pre-mod toString.

Comment: It's 2019 now and both nodejs and chrome pretty-print objects on their own, so coercion (when you add the object to a string) is the only use case you would google this question I believe.

Comment: @Kleson People don't always search for what is possible, but what they dream is possible. Occasionally the answer is "You can't."

Answer (score 0):

You can give any custom objects their own toString methods, or write a general one that you can call on the object you are looking at-

```
Function.prototype.named= function(ns){
    var Rx=  /function\s+([^(\s]+)\s*\(/, tem= this.toString().match(Rx) || "";
    if(tem) return tem[1];
    return 'unnamed constructor'
}

function whatsit(what){
    if(what===undefined)return 'undefined';
    if(what=== null) return 'null object';
    if(what== window) return 'Window object';
    if(what.nodeName){
        return 'html '+what.nodeName;
    }
    try{
        if(typeof what== 'object'){
            return what.constructor.named();
        }
    }
    catch(er){
        return 'Error reading Object constructor';
    }
    var w=typeof what;
    return w.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+w.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-This operation takes lot of time to
   complete, and it's use is discouraged according to mozilla docs: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/proto

-Apparently, modern browsers deprecated .prototype and ECMA6 specifies
   using proper__proto__ instead.

So for example, if you are defining you own object **geoposition** you should call ***__proto__*** property instead of **.prototype**:

```
var  geoposition = {

        lat: window.pos.lat,
        lng: window.pos.lng
    };

geoposition.__proto__.toString = function(){ return "lat: "+this.lat+", lng: "+this.lng }
console.log("Searching nearby donations to: "+geoposition.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how to stringify a Map object:

```
  Map.prototype.toString = function() {

    let result = {};

    this.forEach((key, value) => { result[key] = value;});

    return JSON.stringify(result);
  };
```

Answer (score -2):

Rather than overriding `toString()`, if you include the [Prototype JavaScript Library](http://www.prototypejs.org/), you can use `Object.inspect()` to get a much more useful representation.

Most popular frameworks include something similar.

Answer (score -2):

You can't!

In 2023 Chrome doesn't base it's console output on anything you can control.

The best you can do, is output it to console.log lines which force object coercion.

Answer (score -3):

The Chrome console log allows you to inspect the object.

Comment: Yes, that's true if I output just the object, which is handy. However sometimes I just want to output it as part of a string that I might use to contain other data and it would be nice if I could customize that form in some manner.

Comment: I just discovered that you can use additional arguments in a console.log to output objects inline with a string: `console.log("this is my object:", obj)`.

Answer (score -3):

You can extend or override in JS

```js
String.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this + "..."
}
document.write("Sergio".toString());
```

Comment: How does this add anything to the 2011 answers that give the same solution?

Answer (score -4):

```
A simple format Date function using Javascript prototype, it can be used for your purpose

https://gist.github.com/cstipkovic/3983879 :

Date.prototype.formatDate = function (format) {
    var date = this,
        day = date.getDate(),
        month = date.getMonth() + 1,
        year = date.getFullYear(),
        hours = date.getHours(),
        minutes = date.getMinutes(),
        seconds = date.getSeconds();

    if (!format) {
        format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    }

    format = format.replace("MM", month.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1'));

    if (format.indexOf("yyyy") > -1) {
        format = format.replace("yyyy", year.toString());
    } else if (format.indexOf("yy") > -1) {
        format = format.replace("yy", year.toString().substr(2, 2));
    }

    format = format.replace("dd", day.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1'));

    if (format.indexOf("t") > -1) {
        if (hours > 11) {
            format = format.replace("t", "pm");
        } else {
            format = format.replace("t", "am");
        }
    }

    if (format.indexOf("HH") > -1) {
        format = format.replace("HH", hours.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1'));
    }

    if (format.indexOf("hh") > -1) {
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours -= 12;
        }

        if (hours === 0) {
            hours = 12;
        }
        format = format.replace("hh", hours.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1'));
    }

    if (format.indexOf("mm") > -1) {
        format = format.replace("mm", minutes.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1'));
    }

    if (format.indexOf("ss") > -1) {
        format = format.replace("ss", seconds.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1'));
    }

    return format;
};
```