# JavaScript debugging in Chrome — toString doesn't give me what I need

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As answers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-overload-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu) suggest, you could override `toString()` method on objects to provide useful information during debugging (at least).  This works nicely in Firebug, but this doesn't help at all in Chrome:

```
x = { toString: function () { return 'test' } }
```

gives a very helpful output:

```
Object
```

while in Firebug it's much better:

```
test { toString=function()}
```

I know that Chrome allows me to inspect object properties.  This is useful, but it is much easier to have the object title list at least a few most important ones, so that you don't have to dig through 50 properties of a complex object just to find out one value.

So, is it somehow possible to make debug output in Chrome more useful?

**EDIT**:

This is what I want to achieve:

```
v  [result of ???() on x]
    a: 1
    b: 'foo'
  v c: [result of ???() on x.c]
      foo: 'bla bla bla'
    > bar: [result of ???() on x.c.bar]
```

Comment: Why don't you use console.log()

Comment: @SheikhHeera: And how would this help with my problem?

Comment: @doublep: Why don't you call it exclusively? `console.log(x.toString())`, and if you wish to add expansible version, add `console.log(x)` immediately after it. Will that help?

Comment: @Tadeck: Not much.  In this usecase `toString()` plays no role at all and when I inspect properties of `x`, they are not printed out nicely, again as useless `Object`.

Comment: @doublep: Could you explain it further? You are trying to display `x.toString()` result along with object representation, but you also say `toString()` plays no role for you. Is it the representation of properties of the main object that concerns you?

Comment: @Tadeck: It plays no special role *here*.  Yes, I know I can call a method manually.

Answer (score -2):

You can use it like that:

```
console.log(x.toString(), x)
```

It will give you the result of `x.toString()` and expansible representation of `x` in the same line.

Comment: And when I expand the `x` printed as `Object` I get useless `Object` for its properties, regardless of whether the property values implement `toString()` or not.  This is *not* useful.  You basically told me how I can manually call a method.