# How to return a readable string from an object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a function that returns an object

```
function a(){
    return {
        b:1,
        c:2
    }
}
```

doing a().b will successfuly return 1, but I also want to return something else than [object Object] when calling a(). Something like this

```
function a(){
    return {
        b:1,
        c:2
        toString: 'you got 2 values'
    }
}
```

would render something like that

```
alert(a()) // you got 2 values
```

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to override JavaScript's toString() function to provide meaningful output for debugging?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu)

Comment: You can overwrite the default toString() method provided by Object to return any string you like for any object (individually) or object class (on the prototype of a parent object). Everywhere where an implicit or explicit conversion to string is performed your toString() method will be used to create that string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to define your class `a` and add the function `toString` in it's definition.

```
function a(){
    var _this = this;
    _this.b = 1;
    _this.c = 2;
    _this.toString =  function(){return 'you got 2 values';};
    return _this;
}
```

Now you can call the `toString` function on `a` directly:

```
a().toString(); /*executes the function and returns 'you got 2 values'*/
```

Or you can instance an object from that class `d` you can call the inner function:

```
d = new a(); 
d.toString(); /*returns the same value*/
```

Comment: I need to have my tostring on a() call only