# Why overriden toString() is not called in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, tostring, overriding

I tried to override the toString() but i found that, overridden function in not getting called at all.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), but i am not able to track my mistake.

My attempt:

```
DIRECTION = {
    NONE : 0,
    DIAGONAL: 1,
    UP: 2,
    LEFT: 3
};

var Node  = function () {
    this.direction =  DIRECTION.NONE;
    this.weight = 0;
};
Node.prototype.toString = function NodeToSting(){
    console.log('Is called');
    var ret = "this.weight";
    return ret;
};

(function driver(){
    var node1 = new Node();
    console.log(node1);
    //findLcs("ABCBDAB", "BDCABA");
})();
```

Output:

```
{ direction: 0, weight: 0 }
```

Comment: Where should it be called? `console.log` won't.

Comment: Where is the call to toString?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`console.log` outputs the literal value to the console - it will not coerce your object to a string and therefore won't execute your `toString` implementation.

You can force it to output a string like this:

```
console.log(""+node1);
```

Example:

```js
DIRECTION = {
    NONE : 0,
    DIAGONAL: 1,
    UP: 2,
    LEFT: 3
};

var Node  = function () {
    this.direction =  DIRECTION.NONE;
    this.weight = 0;
};
Node.prototype.toString = function NodeToSting(){
    console.log('Is called');
    var ret = "this.weight";
    return ret;
};

(function driver(){
    var node1 = new Node();
    alert(""+node1);
    //findLcs("ABCBDAB", "BDCABA");
})();
```

Comment: @SunilD. That's true, but I didn't want to put a `console.log` in the SO Snippet because it's not obvious