# toString type function in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Does a toString type function exists for mongodb object. For example I have a mongo object and I access it using mongoose in node.js.

```
x = new Type();
```

I want to call something like

```
console.log(x);
```

Which displays a specific field defined in toString of x. 
This isn't equivalent to object._id.toString() because x is not stored in the database.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: lets say my model is 
x = {
    name: " asdasdas ",
    lastname: "asdasd",
}

I want a toString function which when called gives me only name like 
    function toString(){
         return name
}

This should return only name or any field I define in toString()
I hope you got my point. Similar to java toString or python __str__()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu