# Is there a way to override how a JavaScript object return on call?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

For example,

```
var a = {prop1:'asd',prop2:'zxc'};
console.log(a);
```

and the intended return is just one of the property and not all shown, like

```
{prop1:'asd'} // or just asd
```

Selective property are being displayed only, without going through

```
a.prop1
```

but just

```
a
```

Comment: can you explain your question better?

Comment: Why would you expect `console.log(a)` to NOT show you what is *actually in `a`?*

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `delete` the property from the object by using

```
delete a.prop2;
// or
delete a['prop2'];
console.log(a);
// output will be {prop1: 'asd'}
```

If you are using ES6 you can use built-in Reflect object to delete object property by calling Reflect.deleteProperty() function with target object and property key as parameters:

```
Reflect.deleteProperty(a, 'prop2');
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather... You could create a function that takes an object and a key as 2 arguments, then loop through the object and find the key.

```
function findKey(object, key) {
    for(prop in object) {
      if (prop == key) return object[prop];
    }

    return null;
}

console.log(findKey({prop1: 'foo', prop2: 'bar'}, 'prop1'));

// Output would be: foo
```