# Constructor function return is other than "[Object object]"

Tags: javascript, constructor

When I use the String constructor I allways wonder how is it made.It returns the string you specificed as a parameter even though it is instanciated with the "new" operator like :

```
  var str = new String("Hello World")
  //str == "Hello World"
```

If I make a constructor and I give it a return value it returns an Object when instanciated :

```
  function CreateString(st) {
  return ''+st 
  }
  var MyString = new CreateString("Hello there!")
  //MyString == "[Object object]"
```

How can I create a constructor that returns a value Other than [Object object] ?

Update:
I am trying to create a constructor function that has both properties and a value itself like :

```
   function MyConstructor() {
    this.myMethod = function() {
     return 73
    }
     return 25
   }
    /*I want MyConstructor to have the value 25 and the myMethod method */
   alert(MyConstructor()) // to be 25
   alert(MyConstructor().myMethod()) //to be 73
```

Comment: There are very, very few reasons to create String instances.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a new 'class' or just create something else than an object?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `toString()` function definition in the desired class.

```
function CreateString() {
  function toString() { return 'foo' }
}
```

Example: [Number.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

Comment: Yes. this works. but the constructor itself always returns the object

Comment: @MichaelRitter see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6307570/2013580 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422

Comment: what should those links show me? just because a class has a toString method, the constructor still returns a class instance, not the value of the toString() call (unless you print it, where it automatically calls .toString())

Answer (score 0):

By this line

```
var MyString = new CreateString("Hello there!")
```

you're not simply calling function CreateString, you're creating a new Object of 'type' CreateString (an instance of a function).

I guess what you want is just

```
var MyString = CreateString("Hello there!")
```