# Constructor instanciated with new still has a return value

Tags: javascript, constructor

Why do the built-in constructors in javascript return a value and not an object?They are called with the new operator and They still do not return an object.How can I create a constructor which doesn't return an object like :

```
      new Number() //returns 0 instead of [Object object]
      new String() //returns "" 
      new Date() //returns today's date

      function SomeConstructor() {
      return "Value"
      }
      new SomeConstructor() // [Object object]
      SomeConstructor() // returns "Value"
```

How can I create such a constructor?

Comment: You might want to explore this material on JS primitives: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/

Comment: They DO return a object. it just isn't printing as `[Object object]` because they implement the `toString()` method (which returns the string representation used for printing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructor function return is other than "\[Object object\]"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808464/constructor-function-return-is-other-than-object-object)

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed objects, you can check with `typeof`.

To get the subtype you can use `Object.prototype.toString`

As @Michael Ritter pointed out:

> it just isn't printing as [Object object] because they implement the
>   toString() method (which returns the string representation used for
>   printing)

```js
    console.log( typeof new Number()) //object
    console.log( typeof new String()) //object 
    console.log( typeof new Date()) //object
    
    console.log( Object.prototype.toString.call(new Number())) //[object Number]
    console.log( Object.prototype.toString.call(new String())) //[object String] 
    console.log( Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date())) //[object Date]
```

To answer your second question, just return anything in object form rather than primitive form. The reason can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1978474/427146)

```js
      function SomeConstructor() {
          return new String("Value");
      }
      console.log(new SomeConstructor(), new SomeConstructor().valueOf());
```