# How to extend the URL Class in url module of nodejs to add a property into it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to extend the URL class and add a property to customize it. But its not working.

```
let { URL } = require('url');

class MyURL extends URL {
    constructor(url, base) {
        super(url, base);
        this.base = base;
    }
}
let ur = new MyURL('abc.html','http://www.example.com/about')
console.log(ur);
```

**it logs**

> MyURL {
>     href: 'http://www.example.com/abc.html',
>     origin: 'http://www.example.com',
>     protocol: 'http:',
>     username: '',
>     password: '',
>     host: 'www.example.com',
>     hostname: 'www.example.com',
>     port: '',
>     pathname: '/abc.html',
>     search: '',
>     searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
>     hash: '' }

Notice it doesn't have the base property.
Why is it happening?

How can I make it have the property base with the base provided in the constructor by extending `URL`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `console.log(ur.base)` and you'll see your `base` class instance attribute. The reason why you could not see it before is that `console.log` automatically uses `toString()` method of URL class. So you have to override `toString` in a child class as well and include `base` attribute.

Comment: The .toString() method of URL just returns the url in a string, not the whole object, so that part doesn't seem correct. I'm starting a bounty since I'm also interested in extending the base URL to add parameters and have them show when you log the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the bountied sub-question:

> I would like to know how to have the new property displayed on the terminal when doing console.log(url) here. I've tried with defineProperty(), writable: true, enumerable: true, etc. to no avail. Should show the properties in Node.js.

After research, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870568/10841058) question. Thanks to this method, you can edit the output on node:

```js
let { URL } = require('url');

class MyURL extends URL {
    constructor(url, base) {
        super(url, base);
        this.base = base;
    }
    [require('util').inspect.custom](){
        return `MyURL {base: ${this.base}}`;
    }
}

let u = new MyURL('abc.html','http://www.example.com/about')
console.log(u);
```

This gives, as you can imagine, this output: `MyURL {base: http://www.example.com/about}`. However, if I assume well, that's only half the work done, as we don't have all the other properties printed. I am however unable to have a perfect result.

---

If you don't care about the performances and just want the flat properties, you can use `Object.assign` to make a copy of your object without the class:

```js
let { URL } = require('url');

class MyURL extends URL {
    constructor(url, base) {
        super(url, base);
        this.base = base;
    }
    [require('util').inspect.custom](){
        let res = require('util').inspect(Object.assign({}, this));
        return `MyURL ${res}`;
    }
}

let ur = new MyURL('abc.html','http://www.example.com/about')
console.log(ur);
```

this gives the following:

```json
MyURL {
  base: 'http://www.example.com/about',
  [Symbol(context)]: URLContext {
    flags: 400,
    scheme: 'http:',
    username: '',
    password: '',
    host: 'www.example.com',
    port: null,
    path: [ 'abc.html' ],
    query: null,
    fragment: null
  },
  [Symbol(query)]: URLSearchParams {}
}
```

You can achieve the same without copying using some dirty trick (I'm not sure if it's a good idea to do this though):

```js
let { URL } = require('url');

class MyURL extends URL {
    constructor(url, base) {
        super(url, base);
        this.base = base;
    }
    [require('util').inspect.custom](){
        this.__proto__ = Object.prototype;
        let res = require('util').inspect(this);
        this.__proto__ = MyURL.prototype;
        return `MyURL ${res}`;
    }
}

let ur = new MyURL('abc.html','http://www.example.com/about')
console.log(ur);
```

---

But I must admit, it is a bit obscure to me. In case this is not a good solution for you, another possibility is to use a `URL` instance for the `inspect` call:

```js
let { URL } = require('url');

class MyURL extends URL {
    constructor(url, base) {
        super(url, base);
        this.base = base;
    }
    [require('util').inspect.custom](){
        return `MyURL { base: ${this.base}, super: ${require('util').inspect(new URL(this))} }`;
    }
}

let u = new MyURL('abc.html','http://www.example.com/about')
console.log(u);
```

or the faster and dirtier way:

```js
let { URL } = require('url');

class MyURL extends URL {
    constructor(url, base) {
        super(url, base);
        this.base = base;
    }
    [require('util').inspect.custom](){
        this.__proto__ = URL.prototype;
        let res = require('util').inspect(this);
        this.__proto__ = MyURL.prototype;
        return `MyURL { base: ${this.base}, super: ${res} }`;
    }
}

let ur = new MyURL('abc.html','http://www.example.com/about')
console.log(ur);
```

Giving the output:

```json
MyURL { base: http://www.example.com/about, super: URL {
  href: 'http://www.example.com/abc.html',
  origin: 'http://www.example.com',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'www.example.com',
  hostname: 'www.example.com',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/abc.html',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: ''
} }
```

This can be perfected with some string editing.

---

The last solution I have is to re-create the whole print, by iterating through all the getters of `URL` and printing them / adding them to an object to finally print:

```js
let { URL } = require('url');

class MyURL extends URL {
    constructor(url, base) {
        super(url, base);
        this.base = base;
    }
    [require('util').inspect.custom](){
        let res = {};
        for (var key in this) {
            res[key] = this[key];
        }
        return `MyURL ${require('util').inspect(res)}`;
    }
}

let u = new MyURL('abc.html','http://www.example.com/about')
console.log(u);
```

this gives:

```json
MyURL {
  base: 'http://www.example.com/about',
  toString: [Function: toString],
  href: 'http://www.example.com/abc.html',
  origin: 'http://www.example.com',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'www.example.com',
  hostname: 'www.example.com',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/abc.html',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: '',
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

If you don't care about the `MyURL`  prefix and prefer to have the coloration, you can simply return `res` instead of a string.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! I implemented it [in this temp project](https://github.com/franciscop/server-next/blob/master/src/ServerUrl.js#L43) and so the terminal even shows the colors as expected! That `[inspect.custom](){` was the key thing I was missing, and thanks to all your code snippets and tips I finished it properly

Comment: Glad it helped! And I won't lie, if there weren't the bounty, I would've just given the `[inspect.custom]` thing and wouldn't have tried to find other solutions ^^; Your implementation seems nice by the way!