# Can object hold value by itself and return it

Tags: javascript

Let assume we have object like this:

```
let person = {name: 'Ken', doSometing: ()=>{}, data:{}}
```

or this:

```
let Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.data = {};
    this.doSometing = ()=>{};
};
let person = new Person('Ken');
```

And i was intresting, is there a way to make objects like this, but get name propery when calling object by itself (name can be string, number, object and so on):

```
console.log(person) //Ken
```

instead:

```
console.log(person.name) //Ken
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [valueOf() vs. toString() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485632/valueof-vs-tostring-in-javascript)

Comment: There's not much you can do about `console.log`. `console.log` is a debugging tool, so it tends to display the object as is, even if you override `valueOf` or `toString`.

Comment: The comment from @melpomene suddenly reminded me that I answered a similar question a few years ago and invented a rather troubling mechanic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43416818/710446. Follow my advice there at your own peril.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanical problem with this design is that primitives (like strings, numbers, and booleans) cannot have their own properties. You could add a property to the primitive's associated prototype, like `String.prototype.doSomething = function() { ... }`, which would allow you to do `"foo".doSomething()`. (This is discouraged, though, since you should not [modify objects you don't own](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/maintainable-javascript/9781449328092/ch11.html).) However, you cannot attach a value to a specific primitive string value, which means you cannot implement `data` and `name` how you'd like.

Instead, the best option is likely to use an object with a `toString` method that will allow you to stringify the object to a string of your desired form. This won't show in `console.log` form, but it would if you added an empty string to it, like `console.log(""+person)`.

If you want to give nightmares to anyone who maintains your code in the future, you could achieve this by [having your object include `RegExp.prototype` in its prototype chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43416818/710446). I strongly, actively discourage you from doing so, but suppose I'm not legally capable of stopping you, either; whether or not it should be, (ab)using `RegExp.prototype` in this way is not (yet) a crime in any jurisdiction.