# Javascript user defined prototypes returned with object on console

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I noticed that my console.log prints the object plus any user-defined prototypes.

```
Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function() {
}

Date.prototype.addDay = function() {
}

a = new Date();

console.log(a);
console.log("a - " + a);
```

Outputs:

```
[object Date] {
  addDay: function() {
},
  getWeekNumber: function() {
}
}
"a - Mon Jun 03 2019 13:58:05 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
```

Converting console.log output to a string renders values as expected, but if you just console the object, is there anything that can be done to declutter the console so that only the objects are printed for debugging purposes and the user-defined prototypes are not expanded like the following output when the user-defined prototypes are removed from the code?

```
[object Date] { ... }
"a - Mon Jun 03 2019 14:01:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
```

Not a big deal, but I could not find a similar question so I thought I would ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and set `enumerable` false ..?

Comment: On Chrome 74.0.3729.108 I get `Mon Jun 03 2019 20:14:22 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)` when executing your code.

Comment: Are you running this code in Node.js, or some specific browser? If Node, you may want to create a [`[require('util').inspect.custom]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870568/710446) handler, if simply making the property non-enumerable doesn't work.

Comment: @apsiller - no specific browser, I just typed out an example on CodePen and JSBin - same behavior for both. I'll try the enumarable false property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties are enumerable by default. This means they are considered important to list when examining the properties of the object.

You can use `Object.defineProperty` with the `enumerable: false` to create a property that is not enumerable. It's still there, but it will not be listed when asked to display all its properties.

```js
// Properties are enumerable by default.
Date.prototype.enumerable = function() {
  return 'enumerable';
};

// Use Object.defineProperty to create a non non enumerable property
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'nonEnumerable', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: function() {
     return 'nonEnumerable'; // logic todo...
  }
});

a = new Date();

// Iterate over all enumerable keys
for (const key in a) {
  console.log('enumerable key: ' + key); // only 'enumerable' is logged
}

// But both properties are present
console.log(a.enumerable())    //-> 'enumerable'
console.log(a.nonEnumerable()) //-> 'nonEnumerable'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to just log the date as String?

```
console.log(a.toString());
```

Or if that's too many keystrokes:

```
console.log(""+a);
```