# How to log custom messages on console.log of function reference in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where in I want to print custom message on log of some method reference.

Say I have a `function sum(){}` now on `console.log(sum);` I want to log a custom message on console. How can we achieve that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to override JavaScript's toString() function to provide meaningful output for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu)

Comment: @Thierry yes, it is possible to do that. You simply add a `toString()` method to the function.

Comment: @Thierry This question is different from that as I am trying to log function reference itself not the object created from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```js
var sum = function(){};

sum.toString = function(){ return 'my custom message'; };

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: This answers my questions to some extent. :)