# javascript cast class instance to string

Tags: javascript

In Python I can override `__str__` method of a class, so `str(class_instance)` would return what method `__str__` of such class returns.

Is there any analog way in javascript to define what `String(classInstance)` returns?

Comment: `toString` is the function you are looking for

Comment: yes, there is a way, but what do you have in mind, specifically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to override JavaScript's toString() function to provide meaningful output for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu)