# Changing how an object/function is represented in a console.log statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to customize how an instance is printed in a `console.log` statement by default:

```js
function Vehicle(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.engineOn = false;
}

Vehicle.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return 'print this';
}

let v = new Vehicle(1,2,3);
console.log(v);
```

It seems there is a `valueOf` and a `toString` function, but neither of those seem to change the value. How would I properly change the default format when it's cast to a string in the `console.log` statement?

Comment: See also the entire thread of [Is it possible to override JavaScript's toString() function to provide meaningful output for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu)

Comment: @ggorlen yea that might be the simplest, just doing `console.log('' + v)` to cast it.